# Changing title/author in the middle of a document

Tags: formatting

I am creating an internal "toy" journal for the undergraduates of my university. I grabbed a template of a journal available from CTAN in order to make this toy journal.

When trying to build it up, I made a "mother" .tex and put various `\include{paper1},...\include{paper i }, ... \include{paper n}` to put all submissions together.

However, the titles and authors are being fixed from the first `\include{paper1}`. Even if I change them in paper 2, they don't display correctly (they display as normal text) and the previous titles/authors keep reappearing on pages.

I would like a way to solve this issue and, if possible, references on how to "build up" something like a journal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [combine](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) package?  I think that does it.

Comment: @GarethWalker Thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying to implement the class, but I am having some difficulties. For instance, the following error appears: "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].<to be read again>t \end{align}" whenever I try to include a document.

Comment: You'll almost certainly need to provide a MWE demonstrating the error before anyone helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what's in the [combine](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) documentation, the following code includes two papers as a mock-up of conference proceedings with a table of contents:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{combine}
\title{Proceedings of the ...}
\author{A. N. Editor\thanks{Support ...}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Editor's introduction} \label{intro} 
In the article by A.~N.~Author on page~\pageref{art1} ...
\begin{papers}
\coltoctitle{An article}
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author}
\label{art1}
\import{art1}
\coltoctitle{Another article}
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Other}
\label{art2}
\import{art2}
\end{papers}
\clearpage
\section{Acknowledgements}
Among the many ...
\end{document}
```

This could be art1.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{An article}
\author{A.~N.~Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
My paper.
\end{document}
```

And this could be art2.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Another article}
\author{A.~N.~Other}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
My paper.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and reference. I'll accept your answer and open another question with respect to the error I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Do you have alternatives to this package? [I am having problems with it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340496/tex-capacity-error-when-using-combine-class/).